# Page layout different on 1st load in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]I'm trying to get a job as a developer. I've made a personal website to show employers but I've got a bug. Everything is fine in all browsers except Chrome.

On the first load of the page, the navbar layout is messed up. After you hit refresh or navigate to other pages the proper layout is maintained.

I have no idea what is causing this. Can anyone help?

Link to website: www.alexanderisgr8.com

Comment: I can't see the problem, can you provide us a picture of the bug?

Comment: Chrome 59 - No repo / Does the issue occur on initial load in a new incognito window?

Comment: just tried it and yes it does

Comment: Your chrome's version?

Comment: looks fine to me

Comment: Start by fixing your HTML. https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.alexanderisgr8.com%2F

Comment: Version 59.0.3071.115

Comment: any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i covered up the issue by writing a script to refresh the page once after intially loading it. could not find a true fix.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly a caching issue due to an older css. Try doing a hard-refresh [ctrl+f5]?

Comment: Were you able to identify and/or fix the root issue?

Comment: i was not. it seems to be a chrome issue though.